# wait window.onbeforeprint before window.print pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

window.print() function pop up print screen but i want that before pop up window.print myFunction() should finish its process. So that my program wait to finish myFunction.

```
(function () {
    var beforePrint = function () {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
        myFunction();
        //window.print() pop up should wait until myFunction() finish
    };

    var afterPrint = function () {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

}());
```

Comment: I think you can't 'pause' the printing process. Beforeprint is fired when you or the user calls window.print, but it's just an event. Maybe you could modify "myFunction" to call window.print after it finishes. What does "myFunction" do?

Comment: "myFunction" creates canvas elements for print. These elements are created asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquerys deferred/then functionality to do stuff before print.
Like so:

```
$(function() {
  var filterResolve = function() {
    var defer = $.Deferred(),
      filtered = defer.then(function(value) {
      //do lengthy stuff here
        alert('Before Print');
        return true;
        //or false if you don't want to print
      });
    defer.resolve();
    filtered.done(function(value) {
      if (value == true) {
        window.print();
              //here you can log that the print dialog was shown to the user
             //but not if he hit OK or Cancel
      }
    });
  };
  $("button").on("click", filterResolve);
});
```

But to my knowledege it is not possible (in any browser) to detect if anything was printed. Not even if the user clicked OK or CANCEL  in the print dialog.

Oh yeah, [here's a quiet useless plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lU0riaEABTfbelS6grG?p=preview)